# 2008 V6 Accord tranny problems?

Tags: honda, automatic-transmission, accord

Problem has been consistent for over a year.  When accelerating from a stop car seems to be out of tune with buckling.  Had the car tuned and problem continued.  If I shift with 1st then 2nd then into drive(automatic tranny) no problems.  It just happens when I use Drive,any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! It sounds to me like you have an issue possibly within the valve body of the transmission, but I wouldn't be sure about that. I believe the transmission used in your Accord was not what I'd call one of Honda's finer vehicle part choices. Honda had used a transmission which was not very robust. They used the same one in the Odyssey, which fared even worse. Anyway, hopefully someone has direct experience with your vehicle type and might be able to give you an authoritative answer.

Comment: Thanx Paulster2...will wait other replies too